# User Profile Synch for Claims Based accounts

Tags: user-profile, claims-based-auth

The situation:

I have a SharePoint 2010 Claims Based Web Application with 2 authentication methods enabled: Windows Authentication and a Trusted Identity Provider.

I have enabled User Profiles and My Sites.

After logging in with a claims based credentials through the Trusted Identity Provider and accessing My Profile, a profile was created for the claims based user. I verified this in the Central administration: there is a user profile.

I have created a custom profile synchronization connection, using a BCS that connects to a custom WCF Service. In the service I log every request. The connection uses the AccountName property for mapping.

The problem:

When I run a full synch, only the windows accounts are synchronized. 
The service is only called with Windows account names (DOMAIN\username), and never with the 
a claims based account name (i:05.t|sts|username)

The Question

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can only use BCS to embelish existing windows account based profiles with additional properties (regardless of how they authenticate, which has nothing to do with UPS) the primary source of the account must be windows principals. that is why for example we can't directly sync with AD LDS

Comment: This is too bad. Is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the UPS only syncs Windows Accounts - how could it possibly sync when you for instance use Live ID AuthN; it cant sync all the hundreds of million users that uses Live ID.

Comment: Doesn't it only synch the profiles that are actually in SharePoint?

Comment: You have to remember that the UPS is not a 2-way sync. It's a one way sync on a per property basis. You configure it, using the connections, to sync parts of the AD or other sources.

Comment: I am under the impression that the UPS will try to synchronize all configured properties of all profiles in the Sharepoint Profiles. ie, it will go over all existing profiles in SharePoint, retrieve data using the identifier mapping, and then do something with that data. The logging in my BCS service sugests it works like this, except that it doesn't do all existing profiles, but only the windows accounts. Am I completely off track here?